# SQL - Check if there is data in a user defined type passed as an input to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, case, conditional-statements, user-defined-types

I have a stored proc with user defined type as an input as follows

```
//UDT
CREATE TYPE MY_UDT AS TABLE(
    TYPE [varchar](20) NOT NULL
)


CREATE PROC PS
(
     @UDT MY_UDT READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COL1, COL2...
    FROM tblA
    WHERE
    1 = CASE WHEN /*CONDITION TO CHECK IF THE UDT DATA IS NULL*/ THEN 1
             WHEN EXISTS(select 1 from @UDT WHERE TYPE = 'Red') AND COL2 IN 
                  (SELECT TYPE FROM @UDT WHERE TYPE = 'Red') THEN 1
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @UDT WHERE TYPE = 'Green') AND COL2 
                  IN (SELECT TYPE FROM @UDT WHERE TYPE = 'Green') THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END
END
```

how can we check if there is no data in UDT, to satisfy my first case condition, also in my second and third case conditions SELECT statement is written twice to filter results, is there a better way to not repeat the code? Thanks in advance

Comment: you appear to have an XY problem. What's the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: I want to filter SELECT data based on UDT input, but I got a case when UDT doesn't have any data in which case I would like to return all the data in the table. My actual question is how to check if UDT has any data in the above CASE statement

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree this sounds a LOT like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). But pretty sure you could simplify this to something along these lines.

```
SELECT COL1, COL2...
FROM tblA a
left join @UDT udt on udt.TYPE = a.COL2 and udt.TYPE in ('Red', 'Green')
where udt.TYPE IS NOT NULL
    OR NOT EXISTS(select * from @UDT)
```